# Can the method for producing a spanning set for Nul A fail to produce a basis for NulA?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I use the standard computational method for producing a spanning set for *Nul A*, why does this **always** produce a basis for *Nul A*?

EDIT: The standard computational method is finding the general solution of *A***x** = 0 in terms of free variables. Then reducing the augmented matrix [*A* **0**] to *reduced* echelon form in order to write the basic variables in terms of the free variables

Comment: Exactly what is this "standard computational method"?

Comment: The number of free variables is always the dimension of your nullspace (which implies the standard method gives a basis). Looking at the proof of the rank nullity theorem would probably help with why this is true.